# SingleOrDefault() method: what is "a default value"?

Tags: linq

I'm testing for the existence of a user record in the following statement:

```
if (fromUser.AllFriends.Where(af => af.FriendUserID == toUserID).SingleOrDefault() == ???
```

Given the documentation:

*Returns a single, specific element of a sequence, **or a default value** if that element is not found.*

What does the bold text refer to?  What the heck am I testing for in my if statement?

A serious question that probably sounds simple and ridiculous to most.

Thanks.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Excerpts from ECMA  bible, verse 334 :

---

### 12.2 Default values

The default value of a variable depends on the type of the variable and is determined as follows:

- For a variable of a value-type, the default value is the same as the value computed by the value-type's default constructor (*§11.1.1*).
- For a variable of a reference-type, the default value is `null`.

[Note: Initialization to default values is typically done by having the memory manager or garbage collector
initialize memory to all-bits-zero before it is allocated for use. For this reason, it is convenient to use all-bitszero
to represent the null reference. end note]

The default value of a nullable type is an instance for which the `HasValue` property is `false`. Referencing the
Value property of a default value of a nullable type results in an exception of type
`System.InvalidOperationException`. The default value is also known as the null value of the
nullable type. An implicit conversion exists from the null type (*§11.2.7*) to any nullable type, and this
conversion produces the null value of the type.

### 18.3.4 Default values

As described in *§12.2*, several kinds of variables are automatically initialized to their default value when 
they are created. For variables of class types and other reference types, this default value is null. However, 
since structs are value types that cannot be null, the default value of a struct is the value produced by 
setting all value type fields to their default value and all reference type fields to null.

> **Example**: Referring to the Point struct declared above, the example
>
> ```
> Point[] a = new Point[100];
> ```
>
> initializes each Point in the array to the value produced by setting the x and y fields to zero.

The default value of a struct corresponds to the value returned by the default constructor of the struct
(*§11.1.1*). Unlike a class, a struct is not permitted to declare a parameterless instance constructor. Instead, every struct implicitly has a parameterless instance constructor, which always returns the value that results
from setting all value type fields to their default value and all reference type fields to null.

### 11.1.2 Default constructors

All value types implicitly declare a public parameterless instance constructor called the default constructor.
The default constructor returns a zero-initialized instance known as the default value for the value type:

- For all simple-types, the default value is the value produced by a bit pattern of all zeros:

  - For sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, and ulong, the default value is `0`.
  - For char, the default value is `'\x0000'`.
  - For float, the default value is `0.0f`.
  - For double, the default value is `0.0d`.
  - For decimal, the default value is `0m`.
  - For bool, the default value is `false`.
- For an enum-type E, the default value is `0`.
- For a struct-type, the default value is the value produced by setting all value type fields to their default value and all reference type fields to `null`.
- For a nullable type, the default value is one for which `HasValue` returns `false`.

---

*Amen*

*You could [download the holy book](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029) (version 4.0) directly from microsoft website.*

Comment: For some questions, the full ECMA-334 in StackOverflow syntax would be practical...

Answer (score 4):

Default value for reference types is `null`.  Default value for numeric types is `0`.  There are a few other special cases, but if you ever want to be sure, just evaluate `default(type)` to get the specific default value for any value type you are unsure of.  In your specific case, the default value is probably `null`, assuming you're working with classes.

Answer (score 4):

The default value is the value of default(T) for that type.

But in your case you should use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) instead:

```
if (!fromUser.AllFriends.Where(af => af.FriendUserID == toUserID).Any())
{
    // etc...
}
```

You can also combine the `Where` and `Any` calls:

```
if (!fromUser.AllFriends.Any(af => af.FriendUserID == toUserID))
{
    // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

a default value is whatever you get when you call `default(TypeName)`.

For `ReferenceTypes`, this is invariably `null`. For `ValueTypes`, this is typically 0 (for numeric types) or an instance of the struct after its default constructor is called.

Answer (score 2):

`ReferenceTypes` default to `null`.

`ValueTypes` can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Default value for the element is default(type). For classes default value is null.